# Should approach over water have higher glide path than over ground?

Tags: safety, accidents

On this [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/QZNsbNyRx5g) the pilot says he is above the glide path intentionally because the approach to the runway is over water so that he has more altitude in case of engine failure.

However, we know that statistically although a water landing is more dangerous, a forced landing on the ground is not very safe either.  There are houses, buildings, trees, power lines, cars, fire explosion, or you could simply flip over.

My point is, shouldn't one always fly above the glide path(specially on single engine), whether you are flying over water or ground?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say in the middle paragraph...

Comment: what I mean is that in case of engine failure over ground you also have a lot of risks, so you should fly above glide path the same way this pilot is flying above glide path because he over water.

Comment: I edited the middle paragraph to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to fly an approach higher over water than for flying an approach into a landlocked airport day VFR. The guy in the video screwed up and was very, very high on that approach. Night landings at coastal airports near harbors, bays, etc. would make a steeper approach, more prudent for a pilot, simply to avoid the risk of unlighted sailboat masts.  There have been cases of airplanes striking said masts while on final approach.  Peter O’Knight airport (KTPF) on Tampa Bay has had several such accidents Where aircraft struck sailboats in the harbor while flying shallow approaches into the airport.  But there is no rule on the books requiring steeper approaches during a final approach path over water.

Comment: So you are saying if you are established on final in the glide path (two red two white) on a cessna 172, normal weather, you can make to the runway with no problem with the engine out?

Comment: It’s a fair point, though it is applicable to terrestrial landing at a landlocked airport as well.  I do not prefer to execute normal landings in such a manner.